# Install TFT LCD on Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi

I want to install 3.5 inch LCD (MPI3501) on Raspberry Pi with installed Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS using [LCD-show-ubuntu](https://github.com/lcdwiki/LCD-show-ubuntu) package. I did all required steps. However, it didn't work.(White Screen)

In the 1st step, it uses an ubuntu desktop image But I have installed ubuntu server. I am not sure is it the problem or not.

I connected Raspberry Pi to HTMI and it shows OS terminal as expected